# C# data column to list

Tags: c#, mysql, list

I want to store the incoming data into a list. I have

```
public class Iterations
{
    public string protocol_id { get; set; }

    public string msn { get; set; }

    public string time  { get; set; }

    public string command_id { get; set; }
    public int config_flag { get; set; }

}
List<Iterations> confList = new List<Iterations>();
string protocol_id = string.Empty;
    string msn = string.Empty;
    string time = string.Empty;
    string command_id = string.Empty;
    int config_flag = 0;

conn = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
            conn.Open();
            string query = "SELECT m.`p_id`, m.`msn`,m.`time`,m.`command_id`,m.`config_flag`  FROM mdc_meter_config m";
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "mdc_meter_config");
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables["mdc_meter_config"];
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    // I want to add the row value into the strings
                    // protoco_id = row[col]; 
                    // man = row[col];
                    // time = row[col];
                    // command_id = row[col];
                    // config_flag = row[col];  
                    Console.Write(row[col] + "\t");
                }
                // here I want to do the following
                Iterations i = new Iterations():
                i.protocol_id = protocol_id;
                i.msn = msn;
                i.time = time;
                i.command_id = command_id;
                i.config_flag = config_flag;
                confList.Add(i);
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
```

I am unable to assign the variables to the `datacolumn`. I have looked into this problem but can't find a good solution. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to solve this.

With your code the simplest solution would be:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "mdc_meter_config");
DataTable dt = ds.Tables["mdc_meter_config"];
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    var iteration = new Iterations()
    {
        protocol_id = row["protocol_id"],
        command_id = row["command_id"],
        config_flag = row["config_flag"],
        msn = row["msn"],
        time = row["time"];
    };

    confList.Add(iteration);
}
```

Comment: cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'

Comment: Change it to `protocol_id = row["protocol_id"].ToString()` or `protocol_id = row.Field<string>("protocol_id")` to set the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you look at something like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).

You could then use a class for the fields in the query and get rid of the `DataAdapter`, `DataTable` and `DataRow`.

```
 public class Result
 {
     public int p_id {get;set;}
     public int msn {get;set;}
     ... etc
 }

 IEnumerable<Result> results = conn.Query<Result>("SELECT m.`p_id`, m.`msn`, ... ");

 foreach(var row in results)
 {

      Iterations i = new Iterations():
      i.protocol_id = row.p_id;
      i.msn = row.msn;
      .. etc
 }
```

You could even tweak the SQL to deserialise the data straight into Iterations:

```
var results = con.Query<Iterations>("SELECT m.`p_id` as protocol_id, m.`msn` as msn ...");
```

Comment: Tried your way but I am getting null in my `p_id` but in actual it does have a value `02` stored as a string

Comment: Try adding `AS p_id` to rename the column in the query

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use linq expression to convert your Datatable into a List

```
        //Your datatable
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables["mdc_meter_config"];
        // Convert the datatable to list of Iteration
        var iterations = dt.AsEnumerable()
                            .Select(x => new Iteration
                            {
                                //Get field from datatable, need the field_type in the database and the field_name
                                ProtocolId = x.Field<int>("p_id"),
                                Msn = x.Field<string>("msn"),
                                Time = x.Field<DateTime>("time"),
                                CommandId = x.Field<int>("command_id"),
                                ConfigFlag = x.Field<string>("config_flag"),
                            })
                            .ToList();
```